# Bootstrap panel border not showing properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Angular UI Bootstrap, and I'm having an issue with an accordion. In development environment, with the full version of the bootstrap cerulean file, it shows and works fine, as it should be. The problem comes when I minimize the css file, to pass it to production. Here, the accordion loses his borders, it is still working fine, but it don't see same as in development.

I checked the css properties for both in developers console and they are same, but for some reason, the border-color does not work on the minified version of the file. Here is the code for both:

Development:

```
.panel-default { 
    border-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Production:

```
.panel-danger,.panel-danger>
.panel-heading, .panel-default, .panel-default>
.panel-heading, .panel-info>
.panel-heading, .panel-primary, .panel-primary>
.panel-heading, .panel-success, .panel-success>
.panel-heading, .panel-warning, .panel-warning>
.panel-heading, .well blockquote {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
```

I used Grunt to minimize the CSS file.

The HTML code where this should be aplied is here:

```
<accordion-min heading="Buscar por" class="ng-isolate-scope">
    <div class="col-lg-12 hidden-print" ng-init="estado = true">
        <accordion>
            <div class="panel-group" ng-transclude="">
                <div class="panel panel-default ng-isolate-scope" is-open="estado">...</div>
            </div>
        </accordion>
    </div>
</accordion-min>
```

I'm sorry if my english is not so good, cause it's not my natal language.

I hope you can give me some tip here to see what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked if the style is beign overwritten by some other style in production?

Comment: It's possible that when grunt minifies your css, it's combining in a way that is less than ideal.  I remember recently having a problem something like this---you might need to structure your index file so that the css you've written is in a different area from where grunt automatically compiles the css.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I continued with this and I realized that, to not let the border-color property of the class .panel-default to be overwritten I could use the "!important" tag. So I added it to the regular file:

```
.panel-default { 
    border-color: #dddddd !important;
}
```

Grunt minified it correctly, and now the border of the accordion element came back to normal.

At least, it was easier than I tought.